# Is every integral domain contained in a discrete valuation ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Is is true that every integral domain which is not a field is contained in a proper subring of its fraction field which is a DVR?

Comment: If the ring is noetherian, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a valuation ring, then every overring of $V$ is also a valuation ring. Moreover, these are localizations of $V$. Suppose that $R$ is an overring of $V$ which is a DVR. Then $R=V_{\mathfrak p}$ with $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak p=1$. All we need is a valuation ring $V$ such that $V_{\mathfrak p}$ is not noetherian for all height one primes $\mathfrak p$. In particular, *every* rank one valuation ring which is not a DVR is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't true.  For instance, let $R$ be a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb{Q}$, with fraction field $K$.  If $x\in K\setminus R$, then $R[x]=K$, since for every $a\in K$, $ax^{-n}\in R$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is archimedean).  So if $S$ is a ring such that $R\subseteq S\subset K$, then $S=R$.  Since $R$ is not a DVR, this means there is no such $S$ that is a DVR.

Comment: What if we replace DVR with VR in the question. Then can we say something.

Comment: Yes, then it is a standard theorem that such a valuation ring exists (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring#Dominance_and_integral_closure), for instance).